# Stuck with a Linq Query using DataTables and filtering

Tags: c#, linq

I need some help with a linq query.

Basically, I have a datatable with some columns being enumerated as datarows.  I need to get all the rows that match a string[][].  Example below.

```
string[0][0] = ColumnHeader1
string[0][1] = Hello
string[1][0] = ColumnHeader2
string[1][1] = World
```

Thus, I need to return all the rows that have ColumnHeader1 CONTAINING "Hello" AND ColumnHeader2 CONTAINING "WORLD".

Any ideas to get me started?

Comment: Strongly typed datatables and datarows? Contains or equals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea applied to a DataTable:

```
DataRow[] Filter(DataTable dt, string[][] filter)
{
    var data = dt.Rows
        .Select()
        .Where(dr => filter.All (s => dr[s[0]].ToString().Equals(s[1]))
        .ToArray();
    return data;
}
```

If you are enumerating a DataRow, you can use something like this:

```
string[][] filter;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    if (filter.All(s => dr[s[0]].ToString().Equals(s[1])))
        // this row should be included
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I think this will return the rows you want:

```
var rows = from r in table.AsEnumerable()
           where r.Field<string>(filter[0][0]) == filter[0][1]
              && r.Field<string>(filter[1][0]) == filter[1][1]
           select r;
```